# Django model - changing options in a choices field and migrate

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, django-migrations

I need to change the name of the options in a model status field, which needs to become

> ```
>    STATUS = Choices(
>     ('option_A', 'Option A'),
>     ('option_B', 'Option B'),
>    )
> ```

Before this change, I had the same options but the names where different. Now I changed everything in the project to respect the new names, but the problem is about updating the database in order to display those new names. I use South for data migrations, and as far as I understand it is fairly straightforward to have it write an automatic migration if you need to add or delete a column in the database but I can't find a way to do this update to my existing column.

I use Django 1.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a quick script to make your changes.Something like this:

```
>>Model.objects.filter(status = "some_old_value").update(status = "new_value")
```

Where 'status' is field name.
You can repeat the above step to change any kind of old values to new values in the same model.

Update() is much faster and shouldn't take long time to run on a moderately sized database 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once

Also since it would be a one-time script, speed should not be a major issue.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 6):

What you're looking for is a datamigration.

```
$ python manage.py datamigration your_app_label
```

This will create a new, blank migration in your migration folders. You have to manually create the `forwards` and `backwards` methods to change the data how you want it to be:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    orm.MyModel.objects.filter(status='old_option_A').update(status='option_A')
    ...

def backwards(self, orm):
    # reverse of forwards, or raise an error to prevent backwards migrations
```

You'll need to use `orm.MyModel` instead of directly importing the model for this to work.

Then, simply run the migration:

```
$ python manage.py migrate your_app_label
```

Be sure to include both the migration and the change in your options in the same commit in your version control system, so these will always be synced (as long as people remember to migrate on a new version).

Comment: I am using Django 1.11 and it seems the management command `python manage.py datamigration your_app_label` is removed? And should follow this instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Answer (score 0):

After you change your fields you should run:

```
$ python manage.py makemigrations your_app_label
$ python manage.py migrate
```

(This work for Django 1.7 where South are included into Django package)

In case of Django 1.6:

- pip install South
- -python manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --initial
- -python manage.py migrate your_app_name
- make change to your model
- manage.py schemamigration your_app_name --auto (migration with your
  changes will be added)
- python manage.py migrate your_app_name

Also [here](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#starting-off) are first steps tutorial for South Migration.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said I use Django 1.6. I guess this won't work?

Comment: I know about South, and the output from the automatic generation of a migration (schemamigration) is "Nothing seems to have changed"

Comment: @martina It is possible to write your own migration. But maybe it is not needed to migrate. You can try to chage names in your choices and check if there will be some DB errors after that. It is possible that there is no need to create migration at all.